# Why does a mixed texture with alpha disappear in the render?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency, shader-nodes

I have a neon green texture and a black texture that I mix together using a Mix Shader node, which has the alpha factor coming from an image with alpha (*"DOSE 03"*). When seen from the viewport, it looks exactly how I want. The glare reflection is applied to the neon background but not the black text:

[image]

However in the render the textures do not appear the same. This is Eevee but I tried the others as well:

[image]

Is there something I need to change in my render settings? Or am I trying to make something happen that doesn't normally render? Here are all of my nodes for reference:

[image]

Comment: Hello coumd you please pack your image and share your object? (Only the object with the text)

Comment: Thank you! While I was packing the image for you, I solved the problem. It was a silly error after all: there was another image there in the same location that was slightly overlapping the neon one.

Comment: oh ok great then  ;)